# Move coordinates using QGIS

Tags: qgis

With me I have a csv file. Am using qgis 1.8.5.
I added delimited layer to a map shapefile in qgis. I noticed that some cooridates fell out of the boundaries of the .shp file. 
I selected the coordinates whcih are out of the boundary using "Select Features by Rectangle". 
 I tried dragging the selected coordinates but I wasn't unable to do that. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can't edit those points as they are just CSV display. To edit them (and move them) you need to export those point to a new layer (the simplest option is a shapefile) and then they will be fully editable.

Comment: How do I export it?
I saved both layers as ESRI csv but it didn't work. Also I did save it as a project(.shp) also that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

As HDunn told you in order that you can move the points, these must be in an editable format such as an ESRI Shape file. In order to export a CSV to an Esri shape file, once you loaded the csv file with vector/ add delimited text layer, all you have to do is select the layer, choose save as and select the Esri shape file format. You have to give a name and a coordinate system. Then you have to set the new layer in edit mode (layer/toggle editing) and choose the move feature icon of the digitizing bar. Do not forget your editions with the save layer edits icon